# Get coordinates of line-surrounding box

Tags: javascript, math, line, coordinates

I've been working in JavaScript to code a line drawing system. I'd like the lines drawn to be selectable, so I've been attempting to implement line-highlighting. As you can see in the image below, I have a line (in black) with known coordinates and an equation in slope-intercept (y=mx+b). How can I calculate the corners' (circled in green) coordinates, knowing the box's radius?

[image: line box example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easiest to think of in terms of vectors.

Start off by defining the point at the end of the line as `A`, and the other end as `B`

```
var A = new Vector(1, 1)
var B = new Vector(5, 3)
```

Now find the unit direction vector of the line (a vector of length 1 pointing from A to B), and its perpendicular:

```
var dir = B.minus(A).normalize();
var dir_perp = new Vector(dir.y, -dir.x)
```

And extend them to be of length `thickness`:

```
dir = dir.times(thickness);
dir_perp = dir_perp.times(thickness)
```

The four corners are then:

```
[
    A.minus(dir).plus(dir_perp),
    A.minus(dir).minus(dir_perp),
    B.plus(dir).minus(dir_perp),
    B.plus(dir).plus(dir_perp)
]
```

This obviously assumes you have some sort of vector math library. [Here's one I made earlier](https://github.com/eric-wieser/two.js/blob/master/vector.js)

Comment: Thank you so much. The vector library is perfect as well! :)

Comment: @J4G: I make no guarantees to the syntactic or mathematical validity of the other files in that project, but I'm pretty sure `vector.js` is correct.